# Reading a text file & adding the content to an ArrayList

Tags: java, java-8, java-io

I am learning about all of the different ways to take input from a text file and read through the content. I am struggling to use a try - catch block (with resources), and reading in the file name.

Below is what I have written for this part so far:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    ArrayList<StationRecord> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String stationName = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the filename?");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    File file = new File(input);

    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){

      while(scan.hasNext()){

       stationName = scan.nextLine();
       int yearMonthDay = scan.nextInt();
       int max = scan.nextInt();
       int min = scan.nextInt();
       int avg = scan.nextInt();
       double dif = scan.nextDouble();

       StationRecord sr = new StationRecord(yearMonthDay, max, min, avg, dif);
       data.add(sr);
      }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

I am trying to do this for not only one file, but two of them. Regardless, here is a sample of input:-

Console: What is the filename?

```
TempData2018a.txt
```

After this is entered, I am trying to go through the data in the text file and add it to the **ArrayList** of type *StationRecord* (my other class).

Any suggestions and guidance would be much appreciated! Also any input on how you might do this with 2 files would be awesome!.

Edit: .txt file data example

```
PITTSBURGH ALLEGHENY CO AIRPORT PA
20180101 11 2 7 -22.614762
20180102 12 5 9 -20.514762
20180103 23 2 13 -16.414762
```

I am trying to store that whole first line in a variable called stationName. Then Im trying to store the next int, int, int, int double in an **ArrayList** of *StationRecord* type.

Comment: Well, you're not using your buffered reader at all. You're only reading from scan, and scan is the scanner that reads from System.in. If you want to read from the file using a SCanner, then you need to construct a Scanner, not a BufferedReader. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-

Comment: @Swifty120 Your code is totally incorrect. Why are you using _Scanner_ class for reading states of _StationRecord_ class? Aren't you reading those values from a _.txt_ file? Shouldn't you use _BufferedReader_ class? Would you please post the content of _TempData2018a.txt_ as well in the question?

Comment: what do you mean by two files. you want to apply data to arraylist conversion to two files right?

Comment: @Abhinav Sorry, I haven't learned any of this yet.. The contents of the .txt file are in the edit now.

Comment: By two files I mean I have a TempData2018a.txt and a TempData2018b.txt to read in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Java 7** & **Java 8** *API's* feature, you can solve your problem like below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class LineOperation {

private static List<String> lines;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    lines = Collections.emptyList();

    try {
          lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Abhinav\\Downloads\\TempData2018a.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

          String stationName = lines.get(0);

          String[] arr = null;

          ArrayList<StationRecord> data = new ArrayList<>();

          for(int i=1;i<lines.size();i++) {

              arr = lines.get(i).split(" ");

              data.add(new StationRecord(Long.parseLong(arr[0]), Integer.parseInt(arr[1]), Integer.parseInt(arr[2]), Integer.parseInt(arr[3]), Double.parseDouble(arr[4])));
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

But I strongly recommend you to refer below links for your further clarifications on **Java I/O**:-

1. [Java – Read from File](https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-file)
2. [Read a File into an ArrayList](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-to-arraylist)

Comment: Thank you, this got me on my way. Just have to implement it into my test program. Also good links, I will check them out!

Answer (score 4):

Since this is 2018, please stop using `new File(..)` and start using nio APIs. As you are using Java 8, you can easily achieve what you are trying to achieve here! So, you can create your `StationRecord` like this:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get(pathToFile);

       String stationName =  Files.lines(filePath)
            .findFirst()
            .get();

        List<StationRecord> stationRecords =
            Files.lines(filePath)
                .skip(1) //Skip first line since it has station name
                .map(line -> line.split("\\s")) // split at a space starting from 2nd line
                .map(
                stationData -> new StationRecord(Integer.valueOf(stationData[0]),
                    Integer.valueOf(stationData[1]), Integer.valueOf(stationData[2]),
                    Integer.valueOf(stationData[3]), Double.valueOf(stationData[4]))) // Create StationRecord object using the split fields
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collect result to an ArrayList
```