# Reading content from text file into ArrayList using Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-io

I'm facing a problem with moving content from file to ArrayList. The user selects a line from the file by an index which one he wants to add to ArrayList. I've tried with quick.add(new Pastatas()); But as I see it will add my empty constructor there.

```
private void myobj() {
    File FILE = new File(filex);
    if (FILE.exists() && FILE.length() > 0) {
        try {
            Scanner SC = new Scanner(FILE);
            for (int i = 0; i < FILE.length(); i++) {
                if (SC.hasNextLine()) {
                    String storage = SC.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("ID: " + i + " " + storage);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("select one.");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int userInputas = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            for (int j = 0; j < FILE.length(); j++) {
                if (userInputas == j) {
                    quick.add(/*Probably problem here*/)
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + "error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: What is this variable called `quick` which you're using in the code? And what is `Pastatas` that you mention in the question?

Comment: Pastatas is my class(public class Pastatas implements Serializable {) and quick is my ArrayList(private ArrayList<Pastatas> quick = new ArrayList<Pastatas>();)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a text file & adding the content to an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217833/reading-a-text-file-adding-the-content-to-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer [`Path, Paths, Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) for such tasks.

```
    Path path = Paths.get(filex);
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

    System.out.println("Select one.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lineno = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()); // Maybe 1 based
    int index = lineno - 1; // Zero based index

    if (0 <= index && index < lines.size()) {
        String line = lines.get(index);
        System.out.println("Selected: " + line);
        quick.add(line);
    }
```

The error in the logic:

`FILE` (or `Path` above) is just a possibly not existing moniker/name for a file.
The length is the number of bytes, the file size.
So for a selection of a text line, one has to do something different, like opening, reading, and finally closing the file. The class `Files` provides utility functions to do such things as loading all lines.

---

After reading your comments; maybe something more like:

```
quick.add(new Pastatas(line));
```

In fact if the file is *not* a text file, we would need to know how the file was filled.

Comment: private static final String filex= "oo.txt";

Comment: @HenrikasB so indeed a line number is asked.